# How do I display AppSettings in an ASP.NET MVC web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to display a value from the `web.config` `appSettings` section into a view.

I  am using `<%= Html.Label %>` to populate

In ASP.NET, I'd use `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FileServer"]`.

How do I do this in MVC??

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should be able to just use

```
<%=  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileServer"] %>
```

in your View.

By the way, `ConfigurationSettings` is deprecated - you should use `ConfigurationManager`

Comment: A slight segue but seeing as this is a correct answer, I'd just like to add that any use of magic strings in the app (and certainly the views) is a bit smelly and I would consider using a facade wrapper class on the app settings in order to avoid this. Calls like `<%= App.FileServer %>` are so much nicer!

Comment: Be sure you import the System.Configuration at the top of the page
@using System.Configuration (MVC) or <%@ Import namespace="System.Configuration"%> for webforms

Answer (score 5):

Another pattern, use AppSettingsExpressionBuilder.

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$ AppSettings: sample%>" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the value into TempData["MyVariableName"] using the AppSettings["MyVariableName"] method and then put the TempData value in your view.

In your controller:

> TempData["FileServer"] = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FileServer"]

In your view:

> 

Answer (score 1):

You can do this the same way but this is bad practice. You should prepare all data for display in controller and pass it to the view.

Passing data to the view by ViewData Collection or you can create typed view.

You can check more on that [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views).

Comment: Hey there, I came from the future!

The link is broken. Was it something like this? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views

Comment: if you don't mind, I've suggested a edit. This answer is on first page of google results.